# Nestjs version 9 with Graphql and apollo server v4 gives Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-server-core'

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

While trying to upgrade the apollo version from v3 to v4, getting this error

Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-server-core'

tried: removing node_modules and package-lock.json file but it did not helped, let me know if i am missing anything in the configuration.

```
import { ApolloDriver, ApolloDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ExampleResolver } from './app.resolver';
import { KeelRequestContext } from './lib/app-request-context';
import { AllExceptionFilter } from './exception.filter';
import { APP_FILTER } from '@nestjs/core';
import { environment, EnvironmentFactory } from '../environment/environment';
import { loadEnvFiles } from './lib/load-envs';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [EnvironmentFactory],
      envFilePath: loadEnvFiles()
    }),
    HttpModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
      playground: environment.graphql.playground,
      introspection: environment.graphql.introspection,
      path: '/api/graphql',
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    ExampleResolver,
    KeelRequestContext,
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: AllExceptionFilter,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```